# Multiple instances of a partitioned spring batch job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch partitioned job. The job is always started with a unique set of parameters so always a new job.

My remoting fabric is JMS with request/response queues configured for communication between the masters and slaves.

One instance of this partitioned job processes files in a given folder. Master step gets the file names from the folder and submits the file names to the slaves; each slave instance processes one of the files.

Job works fine.

Recently, I started to execute multiple instances (completely separate JVMs) of this job to process files from multiple folders. So I essentially have multiple master steps running but the same set of slaves.

Randomly; I notice the following behavior sometimes - the slaves will finish their work but the master keeps spinning thinking the slaves are still doing something. The step status will show successful in the job repo but at the job level the status is STARTING with an exit code of UNKNOWN.

All masters share the set of request/response queues; one queue for requests and one for responses.

Is this a supported configuration? Can you have multiple master steps sharing the same set of queues running concurrently? Because of the behavior above I'm thinking the responses back from the workers are going to the incorrect master.

Comment: `All masters share the set of request/response queues;`: I think this is the cause of your problem. You seem to be hitting the same issue as in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1372 but for remote partitioning instead of remote chunking. Do you confirm? Have you tried the repository polling approach instead of making workers send replies to the manager (see figure 6 [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-partitioning))?

Comment: How do I get the repository polling approach? If there's some sample code that allows me to do that that'd be great. Currently, I'm setting the outputChannel and inputChannel to a queue destination on my master step. Is it as simple as just setting the outputChannel (for requests to brokers), not set the inputChannel and set pollInterval property when configuring the master step? And do the same on the slave step? Just configure the inputChannel and not the outputChannel?

Comment: `How do I get the repository polling approach? If there's some sample code that allows me to do that that'd be great`: you can find a complete example of each approach here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotepartitioning. The main test that runs the sample can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/RemotePartitioningJobWithRepositoryPollingFunctionalTests.java

Comment: That did the trick! My issue is resolved after I configured db polling on the master instead of relying on the replies from the slaves on the JMS queues. Thanks for the pointer! Appreciate it.

Comment: ok good to know, glad it helped. However, I want to understand the issue with the message aggregation approach. From the Javadoc of [MessageChannelPartitionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/MessageChannelPartitionHandler.html), I read: `Note: The reply channel for this is instance based. Sharing this component across multiple step instances may result in the crossing of messages. It's recommended that this component be step or job scoped.`. Have you tried a step scoped `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` as requested?